# How to change price value dynamically in Magento based on results from API

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento-1.9

I am very new to Magento. I want to be able to update the price of the item dynamically for the user without affecting its price for other users based on custom fields. I need to find a way to get the data from these fields and submit it using POST to an API and then using the price result from that API to populate the price of the item.

Answer (score 0):

you can do easier by using customer group.

after created go to product price and then set tier price.